# PHP - socket Server

Tags: php, sockets, actionscript-2

Is there anyway to stream a mircophone audio from one flash file to another flash file through PHP socket servers.

I created a PHP socket server with that data's are transfering between two files but I need to transfer microphone audio between them.

I am using AS2 in flash.

Comment: You'll have a very hard time doing this with pure PHP. I understand you're probably trying to create an audio conversation. Why not start with something like Red5?

Comment: @Evert - thank you for showing me the right path....the two flash files are in 2 seperate systems i need to connect them via web server...is there any option to install Red5 in web hosting server...